# Problem on combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

In a bookstore there are four copies of one book 5 copies of another book and single copy of five different books then the number of ways that a person can purchase books is

I tried solving this by purchasing  one at a time ,two at the time and so on till 14 at the time but I could not arrive at the answer.
I am supposed to get 959

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have ,,,

- anything from 0 to 4 copies of the first book (5 possibilities)
- anything from 0 to 5 copies of the second book (6 possibilities)
- anything from 0 to 1 copies of the other 5  books (2 possibilities each)

So $$N = 6\times 5 \times 2^5$$

Subtract 1 because choosing no books doesn't count.